# Returning true if JavaScript array contains an element

Tags: javascript, arrays, boolean, indexof

So far I have this code:

```
var isMatch = viewedUserLikedUsersArray.indexOf(logged_in_user);
    if (isMatch >=0){
      console.log('is match');
    }
    else {
      console.log('no match');
    }
```

If an element is in an array it will return a number greater or equal to 0 and so I can say `isMatch >=0` but this doesn't seem the safest way. How else can I return a true/false from the desired code?

Comment: What's not safe about this? It's just how the function works.

Comment: That's the defined behavior of `.indexOf()` - a return value of `-1` means the value is *not* in the array, and any other value means that it is.

Comment: What do you mean by safest way? Where would this fail? You could use `.find` or `.includes`.

Comment: Wrap it within a function, and return a boolean instead of logging to the console.

Comment: `var isMatch = viewedUserLikedUsersArray.some(user => user === logged_in_user);`

Comment: You can strictly check for the type of isMatch which should be true/false. Here your indexOf will return zero `0` if your match begins at the first position and your check in this case is not good for those situations.

Comment: there's an ES2015 alternative ... Array#includes

Comment: @this.lau_ i just wanted to check. maybe could get messy in an array of arrays?

Comment: @JaromandaX `Array.prototype.includes` is not es2015 standart

Comment: @Maxx you're right, it's ES2016

Answer (score 6):

You could just use [Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```
var isMatch = viewedUserLikedUsersArray.some(function(user){
  return user === logged_in_user;
});
```

It stops when it finds a `true` value

Answer (score 3):

Probably going to get blasted for some reason but hey, why not!

```
function findMatch(arr, user) {
    var i = 0, count = arr.length, matchFound = false;

    for(; i < count; i++) {
        if (arr[i] === user) {
            matchFound = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    return matchFound;
}

 var isMatch = findMatch(viewedUserLikedUsersArray, logged_in_user); // etc.
```

An alternative could also be to use `includes()`

```
var isMatch = viewedUserLikedUsersArray.includes(logged_in_user); // returns true/false
```

Comment: maybe `Array.prototype.findMatch = function(token) {...`?

Comment: What's the difference between this and `indexOf()`?

Answer (score 2):

The One and Only ChemistryBlob answer with `Array.prototype`

```
Array.prototype.findMatch = function(token) {
    var i = 0, count = this.length, matchFound = false;

    for(; i < count; i++) {
        if (this[i] === token) {
            matchFound = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    return matchFound;
}

var isMatch = viewedUserLikedUsersArray.findMatch(logged_in_user); // etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

At first, we have to understand, what is stored in `viewedUserLikedUsersArray` array.

If there are primitives, it's ok, but if there are objects we can't use `indexOf` method of array, because it use strict comparison `===` inside, how we know, the comparison with object is going by link.

`indexOf` works similar to iterating through the loop, the only way.

In case with objects we can use `find` method of array [MDN Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) or `findIndex` [Array.prototype.findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex);

Also we can store users in hashMap with userId keys, and check matching by referring to the object property.

```js
var someUsers = {
  '#124152342': {
    ...
  },
  '#534524235': {
    ...
  },
  ...
};

...

var someUserId = '#124152342';

if (someUsers[someUserId]) {
  console.log('is match');
} else {
  console.log('no match');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use some as it allows the browser to stop as soon as one element is found that matches, so it's going to be faster:

```
const newArr = Array.some((e) => e.name === "amboji")
console.log(newArr);  // returns true if it contains, else returns false
```