# return boolean using .filter()

Tags: javascript, arrays, arrayobject

I am trying to get return a boolean from the below code

```
data = [{name: "Jack", value: "Y", city: "NY"},
        {name: "John", value: "Y", city: "NJ"},
        {name: "John", value: "N", city: "NY"}]
```

*From the above data I want to return a boolean by using filter based on city as NY and who has a value of "Y"*

Tried following ways

```
const trail1 = data.filter(function (item) {
                return Boolean(item.city === "NY" && item.value === "Y");
            });

const trail2 = data.filter(function (item) {
        return (item.city === "NY" && item.value === "Y");                               
    }).length === 1;


const trail3 = data.some(function(item){
  return item === (item.city === "NY" && item.value === "Y");
});
```

***trail1*** returns the array object which satisfies the condition but it doesn't return either true or false

***trail2*** returns true or false based on data. But want to know if there is any better way of doing it instead of using ***.length***

***trail3*** returns false always not sure what is going wrong with it. As it has the city as NY and value = Y exists in the *data* object

***followed*** [Returning true if JavaScript array contains an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39750037/returning-true-if-javascript-array-contains-an-element) ***but that didn't help***

Comment: What should be the difference between `trail1` and `trail2` ?

Comment: ```trail2``` returns true as I used .length

Comment: Do you want 1 result or 3 different results actually ?

Comment: @MickaelB. asks a good question. It's unclear if you want to return `true` also if more than one element in the array satisfies the condition. If it should, then using `.some` (as mentioned in answers) is the way to go.

Comment: Please don't post the same question again. If the duplicate didn't answer your question, please [edit it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61646945/edit) to provide more details

Comment: btw trail3 doesn't do what you think it does. the value in the parens will evaluate to the boolean you're looking for - but you then check if that boolean is equal to the original item object - so it will always return false (note that it will error if `item` is `undefined` or `null`).

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [`Array.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

> The some() method tests whether at least one element in the array
>   passes the test implemented by the provided function. It returns a
>   Boolean value.

`Array.some()` will also stop execution as soon as the test is passed, and won't always iterate all items like `Array.filter()` would do.

Note: if you want all elements in the array to pass the test for the answer to be `true` use [`Array.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every).

```js
const data = [{"name":"Jack","value":"Y","city":"NY"},{"name":"John","value":"Y","city":"NJ"},{"name":"John","value":"N","city":"NY"}]
        
const result = data.some(item => 
  item.city === "NY" && item.value === "Y"
)

console.log(result)
```